# C#/.NET FileAccessControl doesn't prevent file from writing

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm using FAC and adding a new access rule to write.exe. When I right click and check the properties it shows the new rule with "Deny" checked for write. However when I run the write.exe it still is able to write.

Is there a different way for modifying a file's access?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow. As it stands, your question is very hard to answer. Can you please check the guidance at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? Specifically, please include the code that illustrates the problem, it's expected behaviour and what actually occurred. This will undoubtedly enable others to help you out!

Comment: @jeroenh Thanks for the reply. I am trying to block a suspicious file from being able to create files on the hard disk. I used FileAccessControl and modified the rules by "blocking" read/write, yet the file is still able to write to the disk.

Comment: Thank you for adding this context. Did you know you can edit your question to improve it? Editing the question is considered better than adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misinterpreting how file permissions work. You don't give 'files' permission to write something, you can only give *users* or *groups*  permissions to do stuff.

An executable file always runs with the credentials of the user that invoked the program. If that user has permissions to write files in a certain location, the program will be able to do so.

You can change the permissions on the target (the folder or file being written to), for example by making it read only for everyone.